# is there a way to compare drawing objects to letters As 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

A user draws some letters on screen, when he finishes the drawing I want to check it in such a manner as to learn which letter he draw so that I can give him feedback.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Yes, It is called OCR. google about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Mouse Gesture Recognition](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=91)

```
var gesture:MouseGesture  = new MouseGesture(stage);
gesture.addGesture('B','260123401234');
gesture.addEventListener(GestureEvent.MATCH,matchHandler);

function matchHandler(event:GestureEvent):void
{
     trace (event.datas + ' matched !')
}
```

Comment: You are welcome! I have done similar stuff in the past and managed to have good results.